# Regarding number representation

Tags: c, cpu-architecture

How do I find the representation of a Number for the system I am on?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking?  Is this big-endian vs. little endian?

Comment: What is Representation of Number? Big/Little endian or using `./,` for floats?

Comment: The representation of what number in what? The CPU? A file? In memory? Are you asking about your system's endianess? Whether it's 2's complement for signed integers or not? Please be more specific.

Comment: 2's complement or 1's complement??How to know this? in memory?

Comment: @NabinSur: In 99% of cases if you were using a 1's complement computer you'd know, trust me. Probably because it would need a whole room on its own, be as slow as a turtle and burn coal...

Comment: @thkala: coal! In my day we didn't have any of your new-fangled coal, it was 10,000 slaves pulling on ropes or nothing.

Comment: @Steve: so the pyramids were really the first implementation of the Towers of Hanoi?

Comment: @Michael: IIRC historians of computer science are divided, the alternative theory is three attempts to render the Utah teapot before realizing they were going to need a lot more polygons.

Comment: (First one failed, second one to prove the first one wasn't a fluke, third one they upped the poly count but their makefile was broken).

Comment: The 1's complement computer I used at uni also had 36 bit words and were not byte addressable. How do you detect that (other than that the programs were on punched cards)?

Comment: @Bo: With a 6-bit character set so they could be 'packed' into the word, right?

Comment: @Michael - Right, there were only upper case letters in the 6-bit character set. But it could also do 9-bit characters, which would have worked for C++ (if that had been around).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK every modern computer uses binary when representing a number. Experiments have been made with other kind of computers, but they have failed to compete with binary.

However, they are working a [quantum computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer) which work completely different and represent numbers on a completely different way.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to store the number in memory, and then inspect the memory.

```
volatile number_type x;
x = 512.123;

typedef unsigned char const volatile uccv;
uccv *c = reinterpret_cast< uccv * >( & x );
std::cout << std::hex;
std::cout.fill( '0' );
for ( uccv *pen = c; pen != c + sizeof x; ++ pen ) {
    std::cout.width( 2 );
    std::cout << static_cast< unsigned >( * pen );
}
std::cout << std::dec << '\n';
```

Apologies for the `volatile`; I do not recall strict aliasing rules and don't want to look them up right now.

Comment: wow, what a heavy machinery to just test some bits, this is complete overkill.

Comment: @Jens: Your solution works to differentiate between the representations that `int` may use. My solution prints any number in hex, which is more informative and covers a lot more ground.

Comment: well if you want to and think that the OP can do something with that. But also I can't imagine that in C++ it is as difficult to output any integer type as hex, using aliasing and stuff like that. As this question is also tagged C, the `printf` format is `%x`.

Answer (score 0):

To know the sign representation is actually quite simle. Look at the result of

```
(favoriteType)-1 & (favoriteType)3
```

Once you have understood how the three different sign representations work that C allows (see eg. Acme's answer), you will easily work out the values of such an expression for them.

Answer (score 0):

Architectural questions such as representation (word size, two's- vs. one's-complement vs. sign-magnitude) and endianness are best answered with hardware and/or OS and/or compiler documentation.

You can use type punning to examine the individual bytes of a value:

```
T value = ...; // for some numeric type T (int, short, long, double, float, etc.)
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) &value;
size_t i;

printf("%10s%8s\n", "address", "value");
printf("%10s%8s\n", "-------", "-----");
for (i = 0; i < sizeof value; i++)
  printf("%10p%8x\n", p+i, (unsigned int) p[i]);
```

For big- vs. little-endian, you could do something like

```
unsigned int value = 0x01;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &value;
if (p[0] == 1)
  printf("Little-endian\n");
else if (p[sizeof value - 1] == 1)
  printf("Big-endian\n");
else
  printf("Weird\n");
```

Better to RTM, though.